# moodstocks sdk : You already opened scanner with different pair , API key / Secret pair issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, barcode-scanner

While some days before everything working fine but right now i didn't made any changes in my code still i am getting this error while opening path for scanning.

Console Log is here:

[image]

```
-(void) initializeMoodStock {
NSString *path = [MSScanner cachesPathFor:@"scanner.db"];
_scanner = [[MSScanner alloc] init];
[_scanner openWithPath:path key:MS_API_KEY secret:MS_API_SECRET error:nil];
// Create the progression and completion blocks:
void (^completionBlock)(MSSync *, NSError *) = ^(MSSync *op, NSError *error) {
//        if (error)
//            NSLog(@"Sync failed with error: %@", [error ms_message]);
//        else
//            NSLog(@"Sync succeeded (%li images(s))", (long)[_scanner count:nil]);
};
void (^progressionBlock)(NSInteger) = ^(NSInteger percent) {
//        NSLog(@"Sync progressing: %li%%", (long)percent);
};
// Launch the synchronization
[_scanner syncInBackgroundWithBlock:completionBlock progressBlock:progressionBlock];
}
```

& `initializeMoodStock` called from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Comment: show your AppDelegate  code

Comment: Reset content setting of your simulator & test if it is working.

Comment: reset simulator not works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three cases here,

> 1. Sometime you need to reset content and settings of your simulator.
>
> & if not works that mean,
>
> 2. Might be someone has deleted your project from moodstocks developer account
> 3. Or sometime admin reseted your project API KEY & Moodstocks secret key.

Now check 2nd & 3rd case go to developer account check your keys & update it in your appDelegate.

Comment: hi its work for me my client has deleted old one & created new project there on moodstocks developer site.